# Superfish not working in IE 6-9

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, z-index, superfish

I have a WordPress website where it uses a Superfish menu. The menu works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 10-11 but it doesn't show the sub-menus in IE 6-9. The sub-menus seem "transparent" in IE 9. I have searched Google for solutions but none of them seem to work.

Methods I have tried:

- Removing filters (couldn't find any)
- `z-index: 9999999` on sub-menus
- `z-index: -1` on overlapping elements
- `visibility: visible; overflow: visible; opacity: 1` on sub-menus
- Added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >`
- Updated to latest version of Superfish

Here's what I have in style.css which superfish.css overwrites:

```
.menu-main-container {
    background: #60ac5f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%, #3a7539 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#60ac5f), color-stop(100%,#3a7539)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#60ac5f', endColorstr='#3a7539',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    position: fixed !important;
    top: auto !important;
    z-index: 151 !important;
}

#menu-main {
    position: relative;
}

#menu-main li {
    background: transparent !important;
}

#menu-main li a {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    border: none;
    padding: 0.46em 1em;
}

#menu-main a:focus, #menu-main a:hover, #menu-main a:active, #menu-main .current_page_item, #menu-main li:hover, #menu-main li.sfHover {
    outline:        0;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E79E38 !important;
}

#menu-main li:hover ul, .menu li.sfHover ul {
    top: 43px !important;
}

#menu-main ul {
    z-index:999 !important;
}

#menu-main li ul li a{
    font-size: 15px !important;
}

#menu-main li li {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E79E38 !important;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #BF711C !important;
}

#menu-main li ul li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DC8122 !important;
}
```

The website: [tinyurl.com/oyxgnmk](http://tinyurl.com/oyxgnmk).

Comment: offhand, all your ie only styles and scripts are at the top of the page, so they're being read first, then overwritten by the regular ones

Comment: superfish.css overwrites style.css. Look at the code added above.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the fix. The problem was a filter on the `.menu-main-container` class.

```
.menu-main-container {
    background: #60ac5f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%, #3a7539 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#60ac5f), color-stop(100%,#3a7539)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#60ac5f', endColorstr='#3a7539',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    position: fixed !important;
    top: auto !important;
    z-index: 151 !important;
}
```

New code:

```
.menu-main-container {
    background: #60ac5f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%, #3a7539 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#60ac5f), color-stop(100%,#3a7539)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #60ac5f 0%,#3a7539 100%); /* W3C */
    position: fixed !important;
    top: auto !important;
    z-index: 151 !important;
}
```